# How to get variable value in function PostgreSQL in an SQL statement

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am setting a parameter with

```
SET app.id To :appId;

CREATE FUNCTION get_car_Price(price_from int, price_to int)
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$  
DECLARE  
  car_count integer;  
BEGIN  
  RAISE NOTICE '%', current_setting('appId', true);
END;  
$$;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of a (placeholder) configuration parameter, use `current_setting()`:

```
SELECT current_setting('app.id', FALSE);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is working and It is very helpful for us, But we want set this value in the function Like 


SET app.id To :appId;

Create function get_car_Price(Price_from int, Price_to int)  
returns int  
language plpgsql  
as  
$$  
Declare  
 Car_count integer;  
Begin  
   RAISE NOTICE '%', current_setting('appId', true);
End;  
$$;

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your question, but it is too unclear, even in your current revision. Are you perhaps looking for the `set_config()` function?

Comment: Actually, we have create one function inside function some insert queries are there and we want to add one value at the run time 
ex.   SET app.id To :appId;


Inside function call 

INSERT INTO OD_USERS_MB (OD_USER_NO,APPLICATION_ID) VALUES (v_od_user_no,current_setting('app.id'));